# WIFI: Will Not Uncheck "Connect Automatically"

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking

I am attempting to uncheck the `Connect Automatically` checkbox on a WIFI. If I uncheck the box, click to another WIFI and then click back, I see the `Connect Automatically` checkbox checked again.

I already said `Forget` on `Manage Known WIFI Networks`, so it is not listed.

Background:
This computer used to connect to WIFI Network A. We now want to connect and stay connected to WIFI Network B. We said to forget WIFI Network A, unchecked the box for that network, and successfully connected to WIFI Network B.

After a time, and even across reboots, the computer will switch back to WIFI Network A, even though it was successfully connected to WIFI Network B and we previously said to forget everything related to A. We also cannot seem to uncheck the box, as mentioned.

**UPDATED QUESTION:**

(from comment below)
If I wait a few minutes the computer will start switching between Network A and Network B causing issues, as the computer needs to access local devices (printers, shared folders, etc.). I can delete the profile, it does not show, then wait 10-minutes and presto Windows will connect again. There is no way to permanently forget the damn thing.

Thoughts?

Comment: Turn off hotspot that is making A available

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 Wireless attempts to look around for any wireless profiles (transmitters) that might be used - yours or others.

If the wireless profile (yours or one you might use) is there be used (that is, to connect to), then Windows 10 will always pre-suggest "Always Connect"

I have several profiles around here that I never click on (there are not my profiles) but if I click in the profile block, it asks "Always Connect".

That is how Windows 10 works. You must uncheck the box each time, if you are actually going to connect and do not want it trying to connect automatically when you start up.

If in your case, Network A is no longer going to be used, you can delete the Network A Profile.

Admin Command Prompt:

netsh wlan delete profile name="profile name"

**Follow up from the Updated Question:**

Since the connection is somehow stored elsewhere and activating beyond the normal control of the computer, it is necessary to repair the computer.

**A. Start with the Initial Repairs:**

Make sure the wireless driver has been downloaded and available.

Uninstall the wireless driver and leave it uninstalled during the next repair steps.

**DISM / SFC:**

> (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
>
> (2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
>
> (3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
>
> (4) SFC /SCANNOW
>
> (5) Restart when all the above is complete

Now update or reinstall the Wireless Driver and test the operation of different profiles.

**B. If DISM / SFC and new Wireless Driver fails to correct the situation, do a Windows 10 Repair**

> Go to the Media Creation Link:
>
> https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10
>
> Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade
> Button) and select Run. If the Repair will not run as per above, use
> the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key, then run
> Setup on the USB Key.
>
> This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  There are 3 ways to
> proceed, according to the severity of the error.
>
> (1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back
> just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup,
> but generally nothing will be lost.
>
> (2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive.
> Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always
> have a backup, but data is not usually lost.
>
> (3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is
> essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your
> data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged,
> because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally
> easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It
> depends on the precise situation.

Comment: @John The reason for the post, though, is that if I wait a few minutes the computer will start switching between Network A and Network B causing issues, as the computer needs to access local devices (printers, shared folders, etc.). I can delete the profile, it does not show, then wait 10-minutes and presto Windows will connect again. There is no way to permanently forget the damn thing. My apologies for not making the question clear.

Comment: Did you delete the Wireless Profile A with the NETSH command?  My other connection for the other laptop does not try to connect.  Remove the wireless profile with the NETSH command I posted and restart the computer. If you do not touch  it, then it should not try to connect. If it does, something deeper is wrong.

Comment: I added in my answer the SHOW PROFILES command that is part of NETSH.   Run this:   netsh wlan show profiles  and ensure that only profiles you want are in this list.

Comment: @John That was my point. There is no A profile, not with netsh or via the UI. As such, there is nothing to delete. Windows connects to the network on its own and as the information stored somewhere else. My thought is Windows stores the profile via a class ID and uses that class ID in multiple places, one of which got deleted with the profile but another got kept  and Windows uses that. Forget really does forget, but it is there lurking like a ghost waiting to come back.

Comment: That is much clearer now than it was. So you need to repair the computer. I adjusted my post.

Comment: Indeed, unchecking the "connect automatically" box will re-check it without your consent. MS made a huge mistake in this "feature" (which, I believe is really a bug they refuse to fix - there is absolutely no logic in auto-checking something that a user specifically un-checked!!!)